# Retrieve all image files using Dropbox Core API

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I am working on Dropbox Core API with Google App Engine (python). There seems to be some problems with Dropbox-python-sdk on GAE. Therefore, I have choose to use the Core APIs directly.

My app is trying to retrieve all image files from a user's dropbox (with file type permission). But I couldn't find a way to get all files without specifying the root/path (all the APIs stated [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs) requires a specific file path)

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** Dropbox actually recommends not automatically recursing via `/metadata` calls. (See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/bestpractices.)

There's no method to get a recursive list of files, so you would need to use [`/search`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#search) to find files or [`/delta`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#delta) with no cursor to get the full list of files.

Could the [Chooser](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser) be an option here (if you're just trying to let the user pick individual files)?

Comment: I my case, I actually want to load all photos inside a user's dropbox for display purpose. Thus, chooser is not an option. If I use /delta, the first call will actually load all files, is it? I will try it out! Thanks!