# Dropbox API - list all files filtered by mime type

Tags: java, android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to list all images of my dropbox account.

- `/delta`
  does show all files, but I can't filter by mime type or similar. With `include_media_info` I can filter AFTER getting all files, but that's too slow for me and results in unnecessary traffic
- `/search` this allows my to filter, but limits the number of results to a maximum of 1000, I need all images

Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: Hi prom85. Did you see the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270357/retrieve-all-image-files-using-dropbox-core-api

Comment: [`/files/search`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#documentation-files-search) in API v2 allows you to page through results, so that might be an option, but it can't guarantee that you find everything. `/delta` (or `/files/list_folder/*` in API v2) is the only way to make sure you don't miss files.

Comment: Thanks. I just saw that the api v2 started, but in the documentation I looked at there was no link to it... Why do you say search may not return all results? I can't find anything about that in the docs...

Comment: No link to what? The issue with /files/search is that you may miss files that come in while you're paging through the results. E.g. you read the first 10 items, and then a new item appears at the top of the list, but now you've moved on to items 11-20 and you miss it.

Comment: No link to the api v2 docs... And thanks, that's answering my question and helped me... Searching for file extensions and filter out wrong matches by hand is much more efficient than getting all files and filtering out afterwards

Comment: "in the documentation I looked at there was no link to [the api v2 docs]" So what documentation were you looking at? Are you just trying to find https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http?

Comment: I just did oversee https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation and that's why I tried everything using API v1...